# Writing the value entered in a prompt box to textbox in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, prompt

[image]I have the following code and i want the value entered by the ser in the prompt box to the textbox which is a asp.net control how do i do that? Please help.

```
 protected void btnPreview_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        divTemplateDesigner.Visible = true;
        divQueryBuilder.Visible = false;
        int count = 0;
        string[] splitMessage = txtTemplate.Text.Split(' ');
        List<string> parameterList = new List<string>();
        List<string> valueList = new List<string>();
        string newMessageString = txtTemplate.Text;
        for (int i = 0; i < splitMessage.Length; i++)
        {
            if (splitMessage[i].StartsWith("["))
            {
                parameterList.Add(splitMessage[i]);
                count++;
            }
       }
        for (int j = 0; j < count; j++)
        {
            string message ="Enter "+parameterList[j];
            Label lblmsge = new Label();
            lblmsge.Text =
                "<script language='javascript'>" + Environment.NewLine + "window.prompt('" + message + "')</script>";
            Page.Controls.Add(lblmsge);
        }
    }
```

The prompt box is coming properly. But am not able to capture the value entered by the user.

And the HTML goes like this

```
 <div class="page" runat="server" id="divTemplateDesigner">
    <table bgcolor="#0CB1C0" style="width:100%;">
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="White" class="style5" rowspan="2">
                <asp:TreeView ID="treeviewDataset" runat="server" 
                    onselectednodechanged="treeviewDataset_SelectedNodeChanged">
                </asp:TreeView>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtTemplate" runat="server" Height="200px" 
                    TextMode="MultiLine" Width="370px"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td colspan="2">
                <br />
                <br />
                <asp:Button ID="btnPreview" runat="server" BackColor="White" Height="30px" 
                    Text="Preview" Width="120px" onclick="btnPreview_Click" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtPreview" runat="server" Height="200px" TextMode="MultiLine" 
                    Width="370px"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="left" colspan="2">
                &nbsp;
                <asp:Button ID="btnBack" runat="server" BackColor="White" Height="30px" 
                    Text="Back" Width="120px" onclick="btnBack_Click" />
```

you see in this image that box has three placeholders [patient_ID] [Doctor_ID] and [Appointment_Date]
Am opening prompt boxes depending on the number of placeholders in the first box.
Count = number of placeholders

Comment: I would recommend that you do this in JavaScript entirely.

Comment: there is a textbox called txtPreview. which is not mentioned in the code.

Comment: Am too poor in javascript the javascript i have used here is also the one copied from internet

Comment: well then this is a horrible way to even consider doing. If you could post your html code, then you'd get more help

Comment: alright give me a minute i will post the html. You want the whole html file???

Comment: The prompt box thing should happen in btnPreviewClick(). Thanks

Comment: Your code isn't written to open one and only one prompt. You are prompting `count` times. Where are each of these results to be stored? Can you walk us through what exactly you are trying to do? What are the prompts accomplishing?

Comment: among the other things pointed in comments, window.prompt has 2 parameters one is title and other is default text in the prompt, look at http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_prompt.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use Javascript to accomplish what you are after, instead of a postback to the server.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function PromptAndFillPreview() {
        var templateStr = document.getElementById('<%= txtTemplate.ClientID %>').innerText;
        var previewStr = '';
        var phIndexStart = templateStr.indexOf('[');
        var phIndexEnd = 0;
        while (phIndexStart >= 0) {
            previewStr = previewStr + templateStr.substring(phIndexEnd, phIndexStart);
            phIndexEnd = templateStr.indexOf(']', phIndexStart) + 1;
            var placeholder = templateStr.substring(phIndexStart, phIndexEnd);
            previewStr = previewStr + prompt("Please input value for " + placeholder, '');
            phIndexStart = templateStr.indexOf('[', phIndexEnd);
        }
        previewStr = previewStr + templateStr.substring(phIndexEnd, templateStr.length);
        document.getElementById('<%= txtPreview.ClientID %>').innerText = previewStr;
    }
</script>
```

And since you don't need the postback, you can replace:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnPreview" runat="server" BackColor="White" Height="30px" 
    Text="Preview" Width="120px" onclick="btnPreview_Click" />
```

with:

```
<input type="button" style="background-color:White; height:30px; width:120px;"
    value="Preview" onclick="PromptAndFillPreview()" />
```

Comment: thnx for ur time and patience :)